# How do I test these lines of code with jest

Tags: next.js, jestjs, mocking

I'm currently studying tests on ReactJS and can't find a way to test the component below
[image: React Code]

When I run jest with coverage it displays that i'm not covering the line 8 to 10 which I think it's weird because I'm using the data-testid for running the tests
[image: test]]

Here it's the coverage
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the coverage report? It shoudld be under: `coverage/lcov-report/index.html`. You will have there more details what is not covered. My guess it is complaining about the onClick method is not tested.

Comment: @MarekRozmus I think you're right, in that case, how would I test the onClick method?

Comment: @MarekRozmus Nevermind, I found the answer

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a bit and with the help of the comments, I got to solve the problem testing the onClickMethod.
[image]